# Add like on click

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to create a cookie method with the current time, which will first check the data (`like_finger` and `article_id`), and if there is no data, then add a like and update the date, if there is data, then do nothing.

I have a `function`

```
$likes = request()->cookie('like_finger');
$hours = 24;
if ($likes) {
    Article::find($id)
    ->where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours($hours)->toDateTimeString())
    ->increment('like_finger');
}
```

But I can't check it yet, because I got confused in the add like button

I added a button to php.blade and created a function in js

```
<input type="button" id="start" value="Like Finger" onclick="startCombine(this)"> {{ $article->like_finger }}
```

```
function startCombine(startButton) {
    startButton.disabled = true;
    startButton.disabled = false;
}
```

How can I make sure that a like is added when true?

I want that when the button is clicked, one like is added, which will be stored in cookies for 24 hours, I wrote an approximate function of how the like should be added, but it is not perfect, since there is no button functionality

Comment: Apparently you use a template engine. Is it Twig?

Comment: Maybe in here are some things that are helping you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737442/adding-a-onclick-to-the-facebook-like-button

Comment: @LajosArpad no, I do not use

Comment: @Kim2000 there are some parts which strongly indicate the use of a template engine, i.e. `{{ $article->like_finger }}`. So, how do you structure your views?

Comment: I think you are using Blade

Comment: @Kim2000 I have added an answer, but since I do not have experience with Blade whatsoever, it might contain syntax errors. If there are problems applying it, then please let me know.

Comment: @Kim2000 So you'd like to make an AJAX request when the button is clicked, to update the number of likes for that article? Or am I misunderstanding this? Does "a like is added when true" mean a Like HTML button, or that the number of likes is incremented? (Also, when what is true?)

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo I want that when the button is clicked, one like is added, which will be stored in cookies for 24 hours, I wrote an approximate function of how the like should be added, but it is not perfect, since there is no button functionality

Comment: @Kim2000 I've posted "something like an answer" now too. It's probably not spot on or complete just yet though, feel free to supply more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never store any logic in the client side. A great alternative for this kind of feature would be using the Laravel Aquantances package.

https://laravel-news.com/manage-friendships-likes-and-more-with-the-acquaintances-laravel-package

Anyway, since you want to do it with cookies;

We can actually do this a lot easier than thought.

Articles.php

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public static function hasLikedToday($articleId, string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Check if there are any likes for this article
        if (! array_key_exists($articleId, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if there are any likes with the given type
        if (! array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$articleId])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$articleId][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public static function setLikeCookie($articleId, string $type)
    {
        // Initialize the cookie default
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Update the selected articles type
        $articleLikes[$articleId][$type] = today()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
}
```

The code above will allow us to is a user has liked an article and generate the cookie we want to set.

There are a couple important things you need to care about.

- Not forgetting to send the cookie with the response.
- Redirecting back to a page so that the cookies take effect.

I've made a very small example:

routes/web.php

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

    return view('test')->with([
        'articleLikesJson' => $articleLikesJson,
    ]);
});

Route::post('/test', function () {
    if ($like = request('like')) {
        $articleId = request('article_id');

        if (User::hasLikedToday($articleId, $like)) {
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'message' => 'You have already liked the Article #'.$articleId.' with '.$like.'.',
                ]);
        }

        $cookie = User::setLikeCookie($articleId, $like);

        return response()
            ->json([
                'message' => 'Liked the Article #'.$articleId.' with '.$like.'.',
                'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
            ])
            ->withCookie($cookie);
    }
});
```

resources/views/test.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @if (session('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ session('success') }}
            </div>
        @endif

        <pre id="cookie-json">{{ $articleLikesJson }}</pre>

        <div class="row">
            @foreach (range(1, 4) as $i)
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Article #{{  $i }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                            <a href="/test?like=heart&article_id={{ $i }}" class="btn btn-primary like-button">
                                Like Heart
                            </a>
                            <a href="/test?like=finger&article_id={{ $i }}" class="btn btn-primary like-button">
                                Like Finger
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            2 days ago
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                let href = $(this).attr('href');

                $.ajax({
                    url: href,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.message)

                        $('#cookie-json').text(response.cookie_json)
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In Blade you can have conditionals, like

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Example taken from https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

Let's try to apply it on your specific issue

```
@if ($article->article_id && $article->like_finger)
    <input type="button" id="start" value="Like Finger" onclick="startCombine(this)"> {{ $article->like_finger }}
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check now

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX request in startCombine() when the button is clicked.

Your server code processing the like seems to use a cookie named like_finger, so before the request to the server is made you create that cookie:

```
const d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000)); // Expiry in milliseconds
document.cookie = "like_finger=" + d.toUTCString() + 
                  ";expires=" + d.toUTCString() + 
                  ";path=/";
```

(The cookie is set to expire after 24 h with the above values)

Then you want to send that to the server:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "the_place_where_php_processing_code_is.php", true); 
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // When status of the ongoing request changes
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         // Server has processed the like request and is done
         // You can do some "summary" here, like disabling the Like button
         var response = this.responseText;
    }
};
var data = {
    id : 1, // The id of the article being liked, not sure how to retrieve that right now
};
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

..and then you use something like this in the receiving PHP code on the server:

```
$id = $request->input('id'); // $id = 1 (in this case, of course)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with ajax at all, how can I make a request, and where to insert this code into a js file?

Comment: @Kim2000 It's js code that's supposed to be in your startCombine() method. (First block setting the cookie first..)

Comment: okay, now I'll try

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: @Kim2000 It should. https://jsfiddle.net/kjoq48ry/

Comment: there is a button, but how to understand that the like has been added, I still have 0 in my database

Comment: @Kim2000 Ok, this is a book on its own.. Do you see the `xhttp.open(...)` line? The 2nd argument there is where to send the AJAX request. I assume you don't have a PHP file named like that :), so you have to write the URL that works for your server/site there instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238705/discussion-between-torbjorn-stabo-and-kim2000).